# Simple projector problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Please, consider this ("sub")problem:

---

Let $S$ a two-dimensional subspace of a Hilbert $H$ and let $Q\in\mathcal{L}(S,S)$, $Q\neq 0$ and $Q\neq I$, such that $Q^2 = Q$. Show that $\mbox{Im}(Q)\oplus\mbox{Im}(I-Q)$ and there's $p,q,r,s\in S$, no zero,  such that $\langle p,q\rangle = \langle r,s\rangle = 1$ and
$$Q(v)\ =\ \langle q, v\rangle p\quad \mbox{ and }\quad (I-Q)(v)\ =\ \langle s,v\rangle r, \quad \forall\ v\in S.$$

---

I have already proved that $\mbox{Im}(Q)\oplus\mbox{Im}(I-Q)$, but I have had problems to justify the last part. Please, somebody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is that you proved that $S=\mbox{Im}(Q)\oplus\mbox{Im}(I-Q)$ (it's not written like that in your question), then you already know that the image of $Q$ is one dimensional.

Now let $p\in\mbox{Im}(Q)$ with $p\ne0$. For any $v\in H$, there exists $\lambda_v\in\mathbb C$ with $Qv=\lambda_v\,p$. It is easy to see that this assignment is unique and linear map, i.e. $v\mapsto\lambda_v$ is a linear functional on $H$.

By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists $q\in H$ such that $\lambda_v=\langle q,v\rangle$ (assuming your convention is that the inner product is linear in the second coordinate, mathematicians tend to choose the opposite convention). So
$$
Qv=\langle q,v\rangle p.
$$
The reasoning for $I-Q$ is similar.